# In django, can I prevent attacker from re-using a session from one domain to gain access to another domain?

Tags: django, security, cookies

I have a django project serving two different purposes. On one subdomain, let's call it `public.example.com`, I allow unprivileged users to access a portal to edit their profile and settings.
On another domain, `private.example.com`, I give the user access to some management functions.

I have the default django session cookie settings, so when I log in to `public.example.com` and then try accessing `private.example.com`, I get redirected to a login page. This is normal and expected because the browser will not send the session cookie to any domain other than `public.example.com`.

If I copy the session cookie that is sent to `public.example.com` and tamper with the request made to `private.example.com` so that I send the `public` cookie to the `private` domain, django responds with a 200 OK answer and renders the page as if I am a user that has logged in to that domain.

I can not find any documentation that tells me that sessions are limited to the domains that they originated from, other than the default browser behaviour of limiting cookies to their respective domains.

Is it possible to prevent such unwanted access without serving the project on two different instances with two different databases?

Comment: This should be handled by [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization). Users allowed to log in on the public domain should only have permissions for public functionality. If the same user tries to use private functionality—however they may have gained access to the private site—the permission system should deny them.

Comment: Yes, I believe after extensive searching and reading that this is the only way to prevent user access between domains hosted on the same django project, sharing a session database.